# Erase some lines in json file

Tags: python, json

***i have a json file:***

[image: json file]

i want to erase some line in this file ***like this:***

[image: json file modify]

how can i do this with a python script ..?

Comment: Didn't you ***just*** ask this?

Comment: don't understand what yu want to tell me ? sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json
data = json.loads(open("input.json").read())
with open("output.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data["Stock"]["Vehicule"], outfile)
```